# In glcoud cli is there a way to list Instance created in last one hour?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud-cli

I am looking for a gcloud CLI command to retrieve all the instance created in the last one hour

`gcloud compute instances list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the results, like this.

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="creationTimestamp>=2020-12-01T00:00:00"
```

Then, build the timestamp that you want.

Comment: Thanks guillaume, It worked. I modified it
`gcloud compute instances list --filter="creationTimestamp>=-p0h20m"` It gives me list of instances created in last 20mins